# Dojo tree widget now shown in IE

Tags: dojo, xpages

I am using a dojo tree widget in the left side pane in OneUi. It shows horizontal scroll bar if the text is bigger than the width of the panel.

Problem is, in some IE instances the horizontal scroll bar is shown on top of the text and not below the text.

Can anybody tell me any workaround to fix this problem (apart from not using IE)

Regards,

Prashant

Comment: "Some instances" is rather vague. Which versions? Did you try the ie fixes script that make it more compatible? Also what doctype and compat setting do you use?

Comment: And please add some code so we can see what you hav done to solve the Problem so far